# Signalr using Redis backplane not propagating message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redis, signalr, signalr-backplane

I have a .net 4.5 MVC app which I have recently moved over to AWS, so we need to add a backplane to our Signalr implementation. I have followed the steps outlined at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis. I have installed the nuget package and my current configuration looks like this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalrBootstrapper))]
namespace app
{
    public class SignalrBootstrapper
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var scaleoutConfig = new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(ConnectionStrings.Redis, "appSignalrBackplane");
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseStackExchangeRedis(scaleoutConfig);

            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Push notifications are no longer sent at all, and I tried manually subscribing to the channel using redis-cli and nothing is being published. There are no errors and I have tried manually entering the connection details into the `UseStackExhangeRedis` function instead of using the `RedisScaleoutConfiguration` as in the demo linked, but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I found a way to enable tracing in Signalr:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Using the tracing I found there was an error loading a dll `Error connecting to Redis - System.InvalidOperationException: The assembly for System.Numerics.Vectors could not be loaded`, so I added a redirect to the web.config and that fixed the issue

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```