# ASP.NET Framework 4.6.2 SignalR and Redis backplane not connecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, signalr, stackexchange.redis

We have an ASP.NET Forms application that was recently upgraded to .NET 4.6.2. We were using **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** with **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR** but recently moved to **StackExchange.Redis**. Prior to the .NET 4.6.2 upgrade, all was working with Redis but since the change, it doesn't seem that Redis is making a connection.

We have two nodes set up behind an ARR farm running the same application code.

Our Startup.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MySampleProject.SignalR.Startup))]
namespace MySampleProject.SignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseStackExchangeRedis(RedisIP, 6379, RedisPassword, "MySampleProject");
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJSONP = true
        });
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that's changed in our Startup.cs file is the use of `UseStackExchangeRedis` from `UseRedis` with the **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** package.

We have Redis 6.0.10 installed on a CentOS 7 box.

If we revert back to using **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** everything works again.

If we comment out

`GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseStackExchangeRedis(RedisIP, 6379, RedisPassword, "MySampleProject");`

SignalR works but messages are (obviously) only passed through on the same server.

We followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis.

Are there any other configuration changes that need to be made?

Answer (score 1):

I found another post running into a similar issue: [Signalr using Redis backplane not propagating message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274894/signalr-using-redis-backplane-not-propagating-message)

The solution was to enable tracing in Signalr: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Finding "Error connecting to Redis - System.InvalidOperationException: The assembly for System.IO.Piplines could not be loaded"

The following was added to the Web.config

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Pipelines" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

And it resolved the issue.